# Error when installing Ubuntu Server (photo of log included)

Tags: server, system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu fresh on a HDD (single OS) but I am getting an error. I'm not sure what it is, but I have the logs. I have tried completely erasing the disk, reseating the HDD, resetting the BIOS and trying to use a different USB stick, but to no avail.

[image: S]

Comment: Pretty clear errors memory errors. Did you verify the ISO you made the Live Media from? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Memory errors as in RAM errors?

Comment: Could be ram could be in the ISO you used. That is why I asked about verify.

Comment: Checked the iso, it's fine. I checked the last line of the log and it says "Stdout: sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/Output error"

Comment: So hard disk error.